# GraphQL Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, graphql

I want to create data with swipeableForm with graphq, I tried make form with formik, in below I make function for handle submit swipeable form

```
const [execCreateThematic] = useMutation(CREATE_THEMATIC)

  const form = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      name: Yup.string().trim(),
    }),
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      return await onSubmit(values, { spaceId })
    },
  })

  const formFields = [
    {
      label: "Name",
      input: (
        <TextInput
          name="name"
          onChangeText={form.handleChange("name")}
          onBlur={form.handleBlur("name")}
          value={form.values.name}
          mode="outlined"
          underlineColor="transparent"
          placeholder={"Type your thematic"}
          multiline
          numberOfLines={3}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: theme.colors.surface,
            fontSize: 14,
            maxHeight: 94,
          }}
        />
      ),
      disabled: !form.values.name || form.errors.name,
      error: form.touched.name && form.errors.name,
    },
  ]

  const onSubmit = async (values, input) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await execCreateThematic({
        variables: {
          values,
          spaceId,
        },
        refetchQueries: [
          {
            query: getThematics,
            variables: {
              where: {
                spaceId: spaceId,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      })
      console.log(data)
      const gThematic = data?.createThematic ?? []

      form.resetForm()

      if (!input?.type) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigation.navigate("SelectThematic", { ...gThematic, spaceId })
        }, 300)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

This is a component for form

```
<SwipeableForm
        isVisible={isModal}
        formFields={formFields}
        buttonText={"Create Thematic"}
        loading={form.isSubmitting}
        title={"Create Thematic"}
        toggleVisible={() => togglePanel("SelectThematic", false)}
        fullWidth
        closeOnTouchOutside
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit}
        barStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
      />
```

when I tried insert data in form and submit, occurs error like this: GraphQL Error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Thematic.name.

Comment: looks like api/server error - test it separately using graphiql/playground/postman

Comment: I tried playground and success for create data @xadm

Comment: then compare raw network requests detaily

Comment: can you explain detail what's your mean? @xadm

Comment: browser dev tools / network ... /graphql POST request body .... probably input/spaceID arg missing - onSubmit between handler passing problem ... log variables before mutation call